# Robot pose with hector slam

Tags: ros, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I tried the hector mapping and it works fine. I would like to use the localization for the pose estimation. My sensor package is just IMU and laser. So do I need the localization package? I already download the hector_localization package from https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/fuerte/trunk/hector_localization . Is there any tutorial or example how tu use the robot pose provided by hector_slam?? I would like to use this pose for further parameter estimation like velocity or some distances to obstacles. Any help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50045/robot-pose-with-hector-slam/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot pose is published to tf (as the map->odom transform) if the "pub_map_odom_transform" parameter is set to true. It also is published as a [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) message on the "slam_out_pose" topic.
This and a few more ways to retrieve pose data are also documented on the [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) wiki page.

How you use the robot pose is beyond the scope of the hector_mapping documentation. The [navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation) is an example of using the robot pose for obstacle avoidance and navigation (even if it is very complex).

Depending on what you want to do it might or might not make sense to use [hector_localization](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_localization). The description should give you a good idea of what it provides.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-12-09**:
Ok. Thanks. Just a comment regarding using hector_mapping and robot_pose_ekf.  So I can use pub_odometry" parameter, to publish the odometry on "scanmatch_odom" topic. So that robot_pose_ekf can subscribe to odom massage published by the hector_mapping. True?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-12-26**:
Hello. Can you tell me please how to incorporate the IMU to been used in hector mapping??I think using IMU can improve the scan matching by  Hector mapping..Any help???

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-03**:
Hello. I can not find any documentation or tutorial how to use and build the hector_localization. Any help or some sample launch file that might help me??